# BeautifulSoup initialization type Error -- trouble troubleshooting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

The error points to this [line of the bs4 source code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L310)

I'm using a 3rd party module that depends on BeautifulSoup.  I am using it to create DataFrames of NBA players' stats individually and then concat'ing them to make one large DataFrame.  The list comp in the code below works for a few DFs but then errors out with `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PandasBasketball.stats import player_stats

dfs = [player_stats(requests.get(url), "per_minute") for url in full_player_urls[600:]]
all_stats = pd.concat(dfs)
all_stats[::500]
```

Things I've tried:

- Checked that `full_player_urls` was generating correctly.  It is.  It it's a list of URLs like: `http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/burrobo01.html`
- Verified that `player_stats()` was working properly for URLs:
  `player_stats(requests.get('http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bustida01.html'), "per_minute")`
  The above correctly yields a DataFrame generated from a table on that web page. This is working as intended.

Comment: Try calling the `.content` method. `requests.get(url).content`

Comment: @MendelG TY for response.  That returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Try to set the url "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_per_minute.html". As i debug your code it cant find a table that return an bs4 object.

Comment: I think that some of the url doesn't contain tables elements so the markup parameter is None.

Comment: @liontass They all contain tables.  That URL you suggested isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the sites server is recognizing that you are making many requests in a small timeframe and at some point in the loop is blocking you. There's a couple things you could do. The simpliest is just put a little time delay after each iteration. If that doesn't work, let me know, and we can fix that up a bit:

```
import pandas as pd
from PandasBasketball.stats import player_stats
import time
import random
import requests

dfs = []
for url in full_player_urls[600:]:     
    dfs.append(player_stats(requests.get(url), "per_minute"))
    x = random.uniform(0, 10) 
    time.sleep(x)
       
all_stats = pd.concat(dfs)
all_stats[::500]
```